# How do I get the naturalWidth of an image loaded via a srcset?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm struggling with a lightbox script that uses `srcset` to (hopefully) let the browser choose a suitably-sized image depending on the screen size.  The javascript part of it swaps images when requested, and tries to get the natural size of the new image.  The browser chooses from the images in the srcset, so the javascript waits for the image to be loaded using `img.addEventListener("load", ...)` and then looks at the image's `naturalWidth` value.  But this value is not the original jpeg's size in pixels -- it's the width of the container.  What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code, which is also in a [codepen](https://codepen.io/starsoftanalysis/pen/zYaRxqX?editors=1111).

HTML:

```html
<button type=button id=button1>Reload</button>
<div id=div1>
  <figure id=fig1>
    <img id=img1 src="https://picsum.photos/300/150"  
      srcset="https://picsum.photos/600/300 600w, 
              https://picsum.photos/400/200 400w, 
              https://picsum.photos/200/100 200w" 
      sizes="90vw">
    <figcaption id=figcap1>original caption</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```js
const img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
const figcap1 = document.getElementById("figcap1");
const button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
function reload () {
  function onLoad (e) {
    const target = e.currentTarget;
    console.log(`loaded width=${target.width} naturalWidth=${target.naturalWidth}`);
    figcap1.innerHTML = `loaded width=${target.width} naturalWidth=${target.naturalWidth}`;
    target.maxWidth = target.naturalWidth;
  }
  console.log("reloaded");
  img1.addEventListener('load', onLoad, { once: true });
  img1.src = "https://picsum.photos/300/150?random=2";
}
button1.addEventListener('click', reload);
button1.click();
```

Comment: After further investigation, I discovered that this is effectively a duplicate of another question (see above).  I solved my problem by putting `?w=800` (etc.) suffixes on my image URLs and using those to set the `maxWidth`.